# PWA shows Safari controls when being redirected to other URL

Tags: html, ios, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to create a PWA for iOS. This is working fine. The main page of my application looks like this:

[image: PWA1]

As you can see the application fills my whole screen nicely. This page has the URL `https://example.com/scanner`. When the user visits this application for the first time, he gets redirected to `https://example.com/scanner/login`. But for some reason the PWA shows some weird Safari controls.

[image: PWA]

How do I get rid of these weird controls?

Relevant code on `/scanner/`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Relevant code on `/scanner/login`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/scanner/"
}
```

Comment: Which navigation library are you using? Or don’t you use one? React-router maybe. Do you try to set window.location.href instead ? It must be a potential reason to see such safari web control.

Comment: @Nostromo The redirect happens on the server-side in Rust. I don't think it's a good idea to do the security checks on the client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It had nothing to do with the manifest. I was just linking to it wrong. `https://example.com/scanner` is the URL determined by the URL-routers in the server-side web-app. Files and other assets need to be linked static.

Defining the scope in the `manifest.json` solves the issue described in my question.

```
{
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/scanner/"
  ...
}
```